# How to deserialize a multidimensional angular json using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
var data2 = results.FormData["model2"];
```

Below is the sample output came from angular json **data2** to convert in asp.net MVC web api

```
{
  "0":{"RowStamp":2,"Department":"Billing and Collection"},
  "1":{"RowStamp":7,"Department":"Business Development"},
  "2":{"RowStamp":10,"Department":"Construction Management/Design"}
}
```

I have model class

```
public class DeptModel
{
    public int RowStamp { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}

var dictionary = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DeptModel>(data2);
```

Error occured during debugging

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List
```

Can someone help me to deserialize this to model? Much better if sample code provided. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have have a class representing similar structure ? Did you try to use that as the action method param ? Share the relevant code please

Comment: You need a model class contains both property `RowStamp` & `Department`, then use `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize` method or something like that to deserialize JSON object.

Comment: Why don't you use `Json.net` aka `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: Looks like a List of classes to me..... Easy with Newtonsoft

Comment: Where are you trying to serialize it ? If you are sending it to a web api endpoint the model binder will use the serializer and does the job for you.

Comment: You are deserializing only the class, not the Dictionary

Comment: Use Deserialize<Dictionary(<int><DeptModel>)>  ...  Sorry im on bad tablet and cannot type easily

Comment: ok thanks dude. goit it

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolve the problem

Model

```
public class DeptModel
{
    public int RowStamp { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize to model

```
var data2 = results.FormData["model2"];
var dictionary = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, DeptModel>>(data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In usings section add

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

And use following code:

```
var request = JArray.Parse(data2);
var dictionaryResult = keyResponse.ToObject<List<Dictionary<string, DeptModel>>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can deserialize your `JSON` with [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
const string json = @"
{
    ""0"":{""RowStamp"":2,""Department"":""Billing and Collection""},
    ""1"":{""RowStamp"":7,""Department"":""Business Development""},
    ""2"":{""RowStamp"":10,""Department"":""Construction Management/Design""}
}";

Dictionary<string, DeptModel> dictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, DeptModel>>(json);
```